How to manage UI state from child screens in Jetpack Compose
I have a complex UI layout and each consists of small screens. Network requests are made in these small screens and Loading and Error states should be displayed on the outermost screen. When I do this with the shared view model, I stay on the Loading screen because we can send a One-Time event.
As seen in the picture, each list element can be selected and the complex screen inside becomes visible. When a Network request is made on these screens, Global Loading should appear and it should return to Successful State.

What should be the best approach here? Thanks,

You need to implement an event system between the child component and the parent component,
In the child component, set a listener, and from that listener dispatch the latest event of the component (isLoading, Loaded, Error)
and in the parent component observe that state, and based on your logic show or hide the loading.
You need to have a pair-key (componentName, isLoading) for all children in the parent.
When a child component dispatches an event, the parent catches it, and then the parent saves it in an array or any data holder that it has,
Check if all items have isLoading "false", then hide the global loading.
You can implement all logic in the parent ViewModel or the parent composable,
Because I do not have any context about the architecture of your project I can't write the code, however, this pattern is more suitable with the MVI pattern.

I followed the separation of concerns and separated the errors and loadings within the sealed interface. But I had difficulties because Child Composable was removed from the screen during state transitions. Thus, the flow does not progress. I'm using MVVM pattern. I had to do it in a Box so that the main screen was always on. My Loading and Error screens open on top of the main screen. In this way, the child is not removed from the screen. I know it's hard to understand.
